# Compare two columns with one coalesce function

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried this query but it doesn't work, **ORA-00904** error.

```sql
SELECT 
 C.BUSINESS_UNIT 
 ,COALESCE(L.CHILD_CONTR_ID
 ,L.PARENT_CONTR_ID) AS CONTRAT 
 , C.BILL_TO_CUST_ID
  FROM C_LIE_VW L 
  ,CONTR_HDR C 
 WHERE 1=1 
   AND CONTRAT=C.CONTRACT_NUM 
   AND (L.PARENT_CONTR_ID <> ' ' 
    OR L.CHILD_CONTR_ID IS NOT NULL)
```

It seems I can't do this: `AND CONTRAT=C.CONTRACT_NUM`

How can I compare the coalesce column with another column?

Comment: Why are you choosing not to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: I don't see how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below query, you cannot use alias to join a value, instead you have to use complete expression. And you no need to use 1=1 condition as well.

```
SELECT
 C.BUSINESS_UNIT 
,COALESCE(L.CHILD_CONTR_ID
,L.PARENT_CONTR_ID) AS CONTRAT 
, C.BILL_TO_CUST_ID
FROM C_LIE_VW L 
,CONTR_HDR C 
WHERE COALESCE(L.CHILD_CONTR_ID,L.PARENT_CONTR_ID)=C.CONTRACT_NUM 
AND (L.PARENT_CONTR_ID <> '' OR L.CHILD_CONTR_ID IS NOT NULL);
```

Below is the join query if required,

```
SELECT 
 C.BUSINESS_UNIT 
,COALESCE(L.CHILD_CONTR_ID
,L.PARENT_CONTR_ID) AS CONTRAT 
, C.BILL_TO_CUST_ID
FROM C_LIE_VW L inner join
CONTR_HDR C 
on (COALESCE(L.CHILD_CONTR_ID,L.PARENT_CONTR_ID)=C.CONTRACT_NUM ) 
WHERE (L.PARENT_CONTR_ID <> ' ' 
OR L.CHILD_CONTR_ID IS NOT NULL);
```